# Dialogflow CX; RegExp Entities: I want to request a standard format

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I want to build a conversation where customers needs to fill in there customer number. The customer number is always build in the format XX-XX-XXXXXX (2 numbers-2 numbers-6 numbers).

I don't have too much experiences with DialogflowCX or in general with too technical stuff. I know how to request a complete string of numbers with: ^[0-9]{10}$ but how do I manage that I force customers to also type the - sign in their answer.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you build regular expressions at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com), it is easy to use and allows you to quickly test against examples.

For your specific problem, [this is a regular expression which will work](https://regex101.com/r/bvyOWN/1):

```
[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{6}
```

I recommend to not use `^` and `$` unless you really want to restrict a parameter input to the specific entity.

Here is the difference, let's assume the following input

> My customer number is 12-34-567890

A parameter with a regular expression entity type containing `[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{6}` matches the customer number as expected, but the customer number is not matched with `^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{6}$`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I never tought it would be that simple just adding the '-' between. Had troubles when I tried it but I think it is due the ^or $. 

And thanks for the link. I would really want to practice it and try some things with it just to learn and perhaps who knows what it can deliver :D!

Comment: Glad I could be of help. Please don't forget to mark the answer as accepted and maybe consider up voting it.